# Apple IOS & Lack of HTML5 WebSockets Support

Tags: html, safari, websocket

Why won't Apple support websockets on IOS Safari?

This is *really* annoying for me...

I'm now looking at having to implement a Comet/Bayeaux fallback for browsers that don't support HTML WebSockets ;(

Comment: Web sockets are pretty new, maybe the just haven't gotten around to it.

Comment: Well, they had it in a beta version of the iPhone simulator, but pulled it for the latest IOS release. Firefox, Chrome, etc. have supported it for years. Safari 5 supports WebSockets. I didn't think WebSockets were rocket science. Perhaps Apple is afraid of Web Apps taking away from their app store?

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say Firefox and Chrome "have supported it for years." Chrome has had WebSockets support for less than a year, and Firefox still doesn't have them (though they will be in the next release). Thus far, the only released browsers I know of with WebSockets support are Chrome and Safari 5. MobileSafari tends to be a little out of sync with the desktop version, so I would expect to see WebSockets support in the next iOS release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm running an iPad with iOS 4.2 beta 3, and web sockets are indeed supported.

Comment: Can confirm that. Although I think it's the -75 draft that they implemented.

Comment: It's looking more and more likely that [iOS 4.2 will have WebSockets](http://twitter.com/#!/ggoodale/status/29641848760)

Comment: Judging from the [twitter noise](http://twitter.com/dctanner/status/6781675732205568) it looks like iOS 4.2 has shipped today with WebSockets support turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after much researching this afternoon, I'm now using Socket.IO-node on the server and Socket.IO on the client.

If HTML5 websockets are available, it uses WebSocket protocol. Then it falls back to Flash, eventually falling back to whatever's appropriate from: AJAX long polling, AJAX multipart streaming, forever iframe, JSONP Polling.

Project here:

www.socket.io

Guillermo Rauch take a bow. You are a legend.

Would have preferred to write the server-side in Java, but I guess Node.js will have to do. I'd love a bit of auto-complete for the Node javascript... ;( I guess it's hard to keep everyone happy all of the time!

I now have server push in Safari 4.x on iOS ;)

Transition to fall-back protocols is seamless.

Comment: Just for the record, you don't _need_ to write the backend with Node, there are several Socket.IO server implementations in other languages, including several Java ones. See [this page](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/wiki/) for more info.